# What is the Correct Syntax for Connecting Multiple Boolean Checks in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm looking for a shorthand way of doing this:

```
if a == 5 or a == 6 or a == 7:
```

And having it be something like this:

```
if a == (5 or 6 or 7):
```

Now, I know I could do this:

```
if a in [5,6,7]:
```

But I'm looking for something more general that would work when the elements can't be easily put into a list (for instance if they are long variable names or if each element is itself a list)

I'm also aware of the `any()` function, but that doesn't clean it up much (I still have to have a `==` for each condition).

Can this be done and what is the correct syntax?

**EDIT:** I know this can be done simply with a bunch of methods, but I'm asking specifically about chaining comparisons together as shown in the second snipit

Comment: Can you expand on what sort of things "*can't easily be put in a list*", and why you think that's difficult?

Comment: `in` works for most cases.  You can always construct the collection to check membership in programatically instead of hardcoding a bunch of values as well.  You can also make use of things like `itertools.chain` if you want to check through multiple sequences easily.  Other than that, more specialized use cases need more specialized solutions.  As @Robᵩ said, can you give some examples of the problems you need to solve?

Comment: Also, if you do hard code the collection to check membership of, as long as all members are hashable, using a `set` instead of a `list` is a good habit to get in.  For trivial cases like this it doesn't matter much, but for larger collections, the O(1) lookup of a set compared to the O(n) lookup of a list makes a difference.

Comment: @Robᵩ So the case where things can't be easily put into the list is moot because I was asking about other things. Like I said, I'm aware that ```if in``` works perfectly well, but I'm looking for a way to chain equality conditions together if it exists.  I'll try to revise the question to make that more clear.

@SilasRay  Could you elaborate on what ```itertools.chain``` is?

Comment: Long variable names are not a language problem, but an editor problem.

Comment: @wnnmaw - It is still unclear what you are asking for. Could you provide an example in which `if in` does **not** work perfectly well?

Comment: ```if in``` will always work perfectly well, I'm looking to see what alternatives I have and if any of them look like ```if a == (5 or 6 or 7):```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commonly recommended syntax for this is `x in <list>`, as you've described.

```
if a in [5,6,7]:
```

The cases which you claim aren't appropriate work equally well:

```
# Long names
if a in [the_first_of_november,
         the_second_sunday_in_the_third_lunar_month,
         tuesday]: 


# Lists:
if myList in [yourList, hisList, herList]:
```

In my opionion, the clearest use of `in` involves pre-computing the right-hand list:

```
if my_answer in list_of_correct_answers:
```

If you are able to construct the list elsewhere, this is perfectly readable for every case you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can always use the `in` operator for this. If you want to find something inside a nested list, you can always use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). To be honest, right now i couldn't think a case when we couldn't use lists.

For example:

```
>>> my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], 6, 7, 2, 3, 'abc']
>>> n = 5
>>> n in itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list)
True
>>> 
>>> s = 'a' #You can even find if a char exists in the list
>>> s in itertools.chain.from_iterable(my_list)
True
```

And the answer for your question, do something like in the second snippet? No.

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way is

```
if a in (5, 6, 7):
if a in [5, 6, 7]:
```

The first is also correct:

```
if a == 5 or a == 6 or a == 7:
```

The second statement does not do what you think it does:

```
bool(6 == (5 or 6 or 7))
Out[1]: False
```